# SQL join - join first no zero element if possible

Tags: sql

I have a data structure something like this:

```
Company:
ID Name
1 A
2 B
3 C
4 D
5 E

Contact
ID CompanyID Phone
1  1         (12)111
2  1         (12)222
3  2         NULL
4  2         (12)333
5  3         NULL
6  5         (12)444
```

I need to match company with its phone - one record for company. In 70% of cases in my data a company has one contact with one phone and this is easy. But sometimes there are more contacts and some phones are null.

So my logic would be:
- if company has more than 1 contact take 1st not null phone (by ID)
- if it is not possible then phone=null

So results of my query would be

```
A (12)111
B (12)333
C NULL
D NULL
E (12)444
```

It's probably easy but I got stuck with it ;) Thanks for any help

Comment: MIN(id) with GROUP BY subquery and a JOIN on that.

Comment: How do you determine which phone is the first one?  What determines the order of phones for a Company?

Comment: @RBarryYoung You`re right,it needs in the subquery a NOT NULL condition.

Answer (score 1):

```
select a.[Name], min(b.[Phone])
from Company a
JOIN Contact b
 on a.ID = b.CompanyID
```

then, optionals, e.g.

```
WHERE b.[Phone] is not null
```

then group

```
GROUP BY a.[Name]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
SELECT com.name
,MIN(case when isnull(con.phone, 'null') != 'null' then con.phone end) a

FROM Company com
LEFT JOIN Contact con on com.id=con.companyid
GROUP BY com.name
```